# Understand sockets, Client-Server architecture & Clients differentiation

Tags: sockets, client-server

I've read a lot of theory about sockets and Client-Server connection on this forums but some points remains blurred or some answers does not satisfy me completely.

Also, i'd like my words to be confirmed, completed or corrected :

1)_ A socket is made out of IP source (IP of the Client), Port source (a port automatically and randomly choosen by the OS between 1024 and 65535), IP destination (127.0.0.1 ? Something i don't get here), Port destination (developper defined-by port for the server) and protocol type.

There may be something wrong in those lines already.

But considering it is true, how can the server differenciate two processes accessing the server from the same machine ? (Understand, how the developper can make any difference if he wants to prevent multiple access from the same machine).
The only difference would be the source port which is auto-filled by the OS. In this case, it would act like it was a totally different machine, right ?

2)_ I heard there was actually a pair of sockets. One generated by the Client, and one by the server.

Is there really a need for the server to have a second socket ? Is this socket a simple replica to keep a copy in the "Client currently connected"-list or is it a different socket, with different values ?

3)_ When does a Client should "disconnect" ? At each query ? At the end of some process ? Other ?

Thanks for enlightenment !

Answer (score 0):

> 1)_ A socket is made out of IP source (IP of the Client), Port source
>   (a port automatically and randomly choosen by the OS between 1024 and
>   65535), IP destination (127.0.0.1 ? Something i don't get here), Port
>   destination (developper defined-by port for the server) and protocol
>   type.

I wouldn't say a "socket is made" out of those data points; rather a TCP-connection can be *uniquely identified* using just those data points:

```
1. Source IP - the IP address of the client computer
2. Source Port - the port number (on the client computer) that the client is sending packets from and receiving packets on
3. Destination IP - the IP address of the server computer
4. Destination Port - the port number (on the server computer) that the server is sending packets from and receivign packets on
5. Protocol type - what communications-protocol is in use (i.e. either TCP or UDP)
```

> But considering it is true, how can the server differenciate two
>   processes accessing the server from the same machine ?

It can differentiate them because the 5-tuple (above) will be unique for each of the two connections.  In particular, in the TCP packets the server receives from process #2, field #2 (Source Port) will be different from the value it has in the packets received from process #1.

> The only difference would be the source port which is auto-filled by
>   the OS. In this case, it would act like it was a totally different
>   machine, right ?

The server can act however it was programmed to act -- but in most cases the server will be programmed not to care whether two client connections come from the same physical machine or not.  To most servers, a client is a client, and a client's physical location is not that important.

> Is there really a need for the server to have a second socket ? Is
>   this socket a simple replica to keep a copy in the "Client currently
>   connected"-list or is it a different socket, with different values ?

A socket is a just data structure that lives in a computer's memory to help it keep track of the current state associated with a particular network connection.  Since both the client and the server need to keep track of their end of the connection, both the client the server will have their own socket representing their endpoint.  (Note the difference between a "TCP-connection", which you can imagine as an imaginary/virtual wire running from one computer to another, and the two "sockets", which would be the imaginary/virtual connectors at the ends of that wire, that attach the wire to the client-program on one end, and the server-program on the other end)

> 3)_ When does a Client should "disconnect" ? At each query ? At the
>   end of some process ? Other ?

Whenever it wants to; it's up to the programmer(*).  There are startup/shutdown costs to opening and connecting a new socket, but there is also some ongoing memory and CPU overhead to keeping a socket open indefinitely, so the programmer will have to make a design decision about whether he wants to keep sockets open over extended periods, or not.

(*) Note that in a modern OS, if the client program exits or crashes, the socket will be automatically closed and the connection automatically disconnected by the OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those precisions ! The only point i'm left "unsatisfied" is on the words : " and a client's physical location is not that important."

I just realize, in the case you want to avoid multiple connections, there is absolutely no parameters useable to distinguish that... Even though it can be necessary or at least useful in few cases.

To me, that seems unrealistic not to be able to do it, actualy.

Comment: If the server wants to allow only one connection from a given IP address, it is perfectly free to do so.  It can call `getpeername()` on any socket to find out the IP address (i.e. field #1) that the other end of the connection is living on, and if two sockets have the same Source IP field, it can close one of them.  (Note that due to NAT and Proxies and etc, the Source IP field may be the IP address of the NAT/Proxy box rather than the IP address of the computer that the client is actually running on, though)